# how to delete dynamically allocated array c#

Tags: c#

Hello I am a beginner in C#, and I have a problem with this code
In the last btnClear_Click event handler I need to delete dynamically allocated button array elements that I created. So basically I have a main form, from where I call the dialog form where you, as a user can choose a number, and when you enter a number, in main form you get a number of buttons that you previously entered (if you enter 4 you will get 4 buttons from 0-3). Can someone help me with that because I cant find answer anywhere :(
Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button[] btnNums;
        private int digits, prevNum, lastNum;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnSetBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmDialog frmDialogInput = new frmDialog();
            DialogResult dResult =
                frmDialogInput.ShowDialog(this);
            if (dResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                digits = frmDialogInput.Base;
                lblOutDigits.Text = digits.ToString();
                lastNum = int.Parse(lblOutDigits.Text);
                CreateBaseButtons(prevNum, lastNum);
                prevNum = lastNum;
            }
        }
        private void CreateBaseButtons(int prev, int number)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < prev; i++)
                btnNums[i].Dispose();
            int x = 34, y = 70;
            btnNums = new Button[number];
            for(int j = 0; j < number; j++)
            {
                btnNums[j] = new Button();
                btnNums[j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
                btnNums[j].Name = "btn" + j;
                btnNums[j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 23);
                btnNums[j].Text = j.ToString();
                btnNums[j].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                btnNums[j].Click += new System.EventHandler(btnNums_Click);
                this.Controls.Add(btnNums[j]);
                x += btnNums[j].Size.Width;
            }
        }
        private void btnNums_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblOutDigits.Text = "  ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...you're already doing that in your other method. Specifically, the loop containing `btnNums[i].Dispose();`...

Comment: Tx I moved it to btnClear_Click event handler and its working. I will probably have more question about this program because its 4 part program and I am on 2nd part

Comment: @Zile But please open a new question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in  btnClear_Click event handler. Just add the condition to check whether btnNums is null or not to avoid error.

```
if( btnNums!=null)
    {   for (int i = 0; i < btnNums.Count; i++)
             btnNums[i].Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I did it like this but without if statement

Answer (score 0):

I would look to change your code design to use `List<Button>` to maintain your current list of buttons and to simplify your use of module level variables.

Try writing your code like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Button> _buttons = new List<Button>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnSetBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmDialog frmDialogInput = new frmDialog();
        DialogResult dResult = frmDialogInput.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var digits = frmDialogInput.Base;
            lblOutDigits.Text = digits.ToString();
            CreateBaseButtons(digits);
          }
    }
    private void ClearBaseButtons()
    {
        _buttons.ForEach(b =>
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(b);
            b.Click -= btnNums_Click;
            b.Dispose();
        });
        _buttons.Clear();
    }
    private void CreateBaseButtons(int number)
    {
        this.ClearBaseButtons();
        int x = 34, y = 70;
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++)
        {
            var button = new Button()
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y),
                Name = "btn" + j,
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 23),
                Text = j.ToString(),
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
            };
            button.Click += btnNums_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
            _buttons.Add(button);
            x += button.Size.Width;
        }
    }
    private void btnNums_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblOutDigits.Text = "  ";
        this.ClearBaseButtons();
    }
}
```

That should solve your problem, plus it adds some better cleanup by removing the event handler and explicitly removing the buttons from the form.

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution but this is a project that professor gave us and she told us not to use List

Answer (score 0):

Just write this code into your method:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblOutDigits.Text = "  ";

        this.btnNums = new Button[btnNums]; // or this.btnNums = new Button[1];
    }
```